# Unkown error in batch game

Tags: batch-file

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.
I'm trying to run a test to see if the fight label  works, but an error occurs after the player is created. I think the problem has something to do with the variables passed into the fight label, but I'm not sure. All comments are appreciated, and thank you.
Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off
CLS
GOTO :start

:createPlayer
CLS
SET playerMaxHealth=100
REM playerMaxHealth is always equall to 100.

SET playerCurHealth=100
REM playerCurHealth is between 0 and 100.

SET /A playerStrength=%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1
REM playerStrength is between 1 and 10.

SET playerWeapon=100
REM playerWeapon is between 100 and 200. It's multiplied by playerStrength to get playerAttack.

SET playerDefense=8
REM playerDefense is used to get playerTotalDefense.

SET playerArmor=100
REM playerArmor is between 100 and 200. It's multiplied with playerDefense to get playerTotalDefense.
GOTO :eof

:fight
REM %1 = playerCurHealth, %2 = playerStrength, %3 = playerWeapon, %4 = playerDefense, %5 = playerArmor
REM %6 = enemyHealth, %7 = enemyStrength, %8 = enemyDefense, %9 = enemyGold
SET playerCurHealth= %1
SET playerStrength= %2
SET playerWeapon= %3
SET playerDefense= %4
SET playerArmor= %5
SET enemyHealth= %6
SET enemyStrength= %7
SET enemyDefense= %8
SET enemyGold= %9

:repeat
CALL :enemysTurn %playerCurHealth% %playerDefense% %playerArmor% %enemyStrength%
IF %playerCurHealth% LEQ 0 (
    SET win=false
    GOTO :lost
)
CALL :playersTurn %playerStrength% %playerWeapon% %enemyHealth% %enemyDefense%
IF %enemyHealth% LEQ 0 (
    SET win=true
    GOTO :won %enemyGold%
)
PAUSE
GOTO :repeat

:enemysTurn
SET playerCurHealth= %1
SET playerDefense= %2
SET playerArmor= %3
SET enemyStrength= %4
SET /A attack= %enemyStrength% * ((100 + (%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1)) / 100)
SET /A defense= 100 - (%playerDefense% * (%playerArmor% / 100))
SET /A damage= %attack% * %defense% / 100
SET /A playerCurHealth= %playerCurHealth% - %damage%
ECHO Player health: %playerCurHealth%
GOTO :eof

:playersTurn
SET playerStrength= %1
SET playerWeapon= %2
SET enemyHealth= %3
SET enemyDefense= %4
SET /A attack= (%playerStrength% * (%playerWeapon% / 100)) * ((100 + (%RANDOM% * 10 / 32768 + 1)) / 100)
SET /A defense= 100 - %enemyDefense%
SET /A damage= %attack% * %defense% / 100
SET /A enemyHealth= %enemyHealth% - %damage%
ECHO Enemy Health: %enemyHealth%
GOTO :eof

:start
CLS
CALL :createPlayer
ECHO %playerMaxHealth%
ECHO %playerCurHealth%
ECHO %playerStrength%
ECHO %playerWeapon%
ECHO %playerDefense%
ECHO %playerArmor%
PAUSE
GOTO :fight %playerCurHealth% %playerStrength% %playerWeapon% %playerDefense% %playerArmor% 70 5 7 50
```

EDIT: The error is **Missing operand**. I expected the label repeat to run until one of the healths was equal to or below zero, and then an error would be thrown because there is no win or lose label. I figured out the problem happens when the file tries to **GOTO :fight** with the variables.

Comment: What is the error? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? What steps have you taken so far to try and troubleshoot the problem yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `GOTO :fight %playerCurHealth% ...`, use `CALL :fight %playerCurHealth% ...`.

> [The `CALL` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) will pass control to the statement after the
>   label specified along with any specified parameters.